# Java: Re-running user input in program after invalid entry (loop?)

Tags: java, loops

After making an invalid entry, the invalid entry loop continues to appear in this program. I am seeking to keep asking the user for input until he/she enters valid data. Then I'd like to use that input to continue on with the program. I'm positive there's a type of loop associated with this. Thanks for your help.

```
identInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a student ID: ");
intID = Integer.parseInt(identInput);
savedIntID = Integer.parseInt(identInput);

for(x = 0; x < studentIDs.length; ++x)
{
    if(identInput.equals(studentIDs[x]))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first name associated with \nStudent ID "
                + intID + " is: " + firstNames[x] + "\n" + firstNames[x] + "'s current GPA is: "
                + gPAs[x]);

        inputTruth = true;
        break;
    }
}

//The following will show up and continue to if the data is incorrect. Am not
//sure how to reuse if good data are entered.

while(inputTruth == false)
{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The Student ID you entered "
            + savedIntID + "\nis not valid. \nPlease enter another Student ID: ");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inputTruth = false;
while(inputTruth == false)
{
identInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a student ID: ");
intID = Integer.parseInt(identInput);
savedIntID = Integer.parseInt(identInput);

for(x = 0; x < studentIDs.length; ++x)
{
    if(identInput.equals(studentIDs[x]))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first name associated with \nStudent ID "
                + intID + " is: " + firstNames[x] + "\n" + firstNames[x] + "'s current GPA is: "
                + gPAs[x]);

        inputTruth = true;
        break;
    }
}

//The following will show up and continue to if the data is incorrect. Am not
//sure how to reuse if good data are entered.

if(inputTruth == false)
{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The Student ID you entered "
            + savedIntID + "\nis not valid. \nPlease enter another Student ID: ");
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although same as the comment above, the program continues to ask for valid inputs even after correct data is entered. Any ideas on how to reuse data?

Comment: If you it does not work with correct data, the problem is in if(identInput.equals(studentIDs[x])). Try to log what is there with System.out.println(...) and also log the stundentIDs[x].

Answer (score 1):

You just Need a while loop

```
while(!isInputValid){
 //Take your input
 if(check == input){
   isInputValid = true;
 }else{
  //Please enter valid input try again.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want ?

```
inputTruth = false;

while(inputTruth == false)
{
  for(x = 0; x < studentIDs.length; ++x)
  {     
    if(identInput.equals(studentIDs[x]))
    {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The first name associated with \nStudent ID "
       + intID + " is: " + firstNames[x] + "\n" + firstNames[x] + "'s current GPA is: " 
       + gPAs[x]);

     inputTruth = true;
     break;
   }
 }
 if (inputTruth == false) {
 identInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "The Student ID you entered " 
  + savedIntID + "\nis not valid. \nPlease enter another Student ID: ");
  }
}
```

Comment: sort of, this works, but after the program recognizes the incorrect data, it just continues to ask... regardless if correct data is entered thereafter. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: my mistake, would you please try this one? feel free to tell me if it doesn't work

Comment: No worries, your help is appreciated. What needed to happen is to start the while loop before the user make his/her input. Thanks again!